# How to type this component in Flowtype

Tags: reactjs, flowtype, create-react-app

I have this component in React which dynamically loads another component using `import()`. the component is based on this blog post https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-code-splitting/

```
    // @flow

    import * as React from 'react';

    type Props = { 
       load: () => Promise<any> 
    };

    type State = {
        component: ?React.Element<any>,
    };

    export default class DynamicImport extends React.Component<Props, State> {
      state = {
          component: null,
      };

      componentWillMount() {
        this.props
            .load()
            .then(component => {
                this.setState(() => ({
                   component: component.default ? component.default : component,
                }));
             })
             .catch(err => {
                 console.log(err);
             });
        }

      render() {
        if (Boolean(this.state.component) === false) {
          return <div>Loading..</div>;
        } else {
          const Component: Class<any> = this.state.component;
          return <Component {...this.props} />;
        }
      }
    }
```

I used it like so: `<DynamicImport load={() => import('./path/to/Component')}/>`

I'm also using Flowtype to type check the project and my question is how this component can be typed, I'm constantly getting errors around the initial state as null.

```
Cannot assign this.state.component to Component because:
• null or undefined [1] is incompatible with statics of any [2].
• React.Element [3] is incompatible with statics of any [2].
• null [4] is incompatible with statics of any [2].

[1][3]  9│       component: ?React.Element<any>,
         :
   [4] 14│         component: null,
         :
       31│         if (Boolean(this.state.component) === false) {
       32│           return <div>Loading..</div>;
       33│         } else {
   [2] 34│           const Component: Class<any> = this.state.component;
       35│           return <Component {...this.props} />;
       36│         }
       37│       }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `React.ComponentType<>` to define the type of a React Component.

Also, your refinement to determine if the component property is set is not recognised by flow, hence it erroring that it might be null.

([Try](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQiCWBbADrATgF1AFSgCGAzqAEoCmxAxvpNrGqAOTY32sDcyuAnhiqgACkwzkAvKADeoRKEVxiAEwBcoABQBKUJIB8opmhSkqAHmIA7focQBfXogFDQAZVzFcw6TIWLQWmYsKyorXA0Afmo6XAA6AGFg2FDwgBVBCzFYCX0AGgcnKgAPLDxQFSpIYgBXaHxaaDJyABF+K2ITWgBJTBx8Eu8rFXIY+kTk1NxzbIk8909vQz9FUkWfWX8AwMmwiNArOugCxUdkRSC+qYB1FGhoAFlYGvCdTe3cAAtTOIxxUi221AcWUKh0gO2cS+YU0lxCez0ywhQMUXx+ZlwHi8VE0bwMWhWKKJOyuew0cJSezilWqdXwkRJ8PC1KqtXqoHJu3CJ2JAXs2m0vF5-ORATitC8tE+mio2GwiPevICQSspFg0CoINgAHMZXLBaLTgbtvZzqAOMNZW9CYoUJAtABCNGkOJrbHirm4XQ2gIcXA1bBWUDmFQoABu+gAMrBVCgrNq4nFzMBQxGhXzQFRoGZFdsVWtQElSeENGN4kWmbgMkIZv9DNJna71h7i7h09s-QGg+YK5TwrJE1Dvi6-jlSPZQMB9O3QKbTg4gA))

```
// @flow

import * as React from 'react';

type Props = { 
   load: () => Promise<any> 
};

type State = {
    component: ?React.ComponentType<Props>,
};

export default class DynamicImport extends React.Component<Props, State> {
  state = {
      component: null,
  };

  componentWillMount() {
    this.props
        .load()
        .then(component => {
            this.setState(() => ({
               component: component.default ? component.default : component,
            }));
         })
         .catch(err => {
             console.log(err);
         });
    }

  render() {
    if (!this.state.component) {
      return <div>Loading..</div>;
    } else {
      const Component: React.ComponentType<Props> = this.state.component;
      return <Component {...this.props} />;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks, worked perfectly! the only thing is that i prefer the other type of refinement using Boolean() (which i think is more readable), do you consider it maybe a bug?

Comment: If you read up on type refinement in flow, you’ll see that passing the value of the property into Boolean would count as a refinement invalidation (you’re invoking a function with possible side effects). Flows type refinements rely on coercing properties to true/false, which requires little if an special case handling. I’ve encountered places where this is not perfect, so there are possible bugs, but I don’t think this is one.  Array.isArray is a special case which is handled, but Buffer.isBuffer is not, for example (js core vs node perhaps).

Comment: You might argue that constructors for known types are valid special cases, file an issue with flow if you think it so.